# how to extract the elements of the output of FactorInteger function?

Tags: factorization

For example, when I evaluate

```
FactorInteger[265^2 - 87463]
```

the output is

> ```
> {{-1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {13, 2}, {17, 1}}
> ```

I would like to put the primes: -1, 2, 3, 13, 17 into the first row of a matrix and put the exponents: 1, 1, 1, 2, 1 into the second row of a matrix.

How can do this?

Comment: What have you tried? (Other than sending a note to a public forum I mean.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Transpose@FactorInteger[265^2 - 87463]
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete the OP's question:

```
MatrixForm@Transpose@FactorInteger[265^2 - 87463]
```

Comment: Using `MatrixForm` does not produce a matrix (i.e., try `MatrixQ` on your expression). `MatrixForm` is a wrapper that affects the display of a matrix. Typically you would use something like `MatrixForm[m = Transpose@FactorInteger[265^2 - 87463]]` where `m` is the matrix and can be used in subsequent calculations because the display wrapper is separated from the definition of the matrix.